# swift: setting the background image of a UIButton that has an action, programatically

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, background-image, xcode7

I have created a UIButton that has an action. I have set the background image of it during compile time (before running, not programatically). I am trying to change the background image of it to something else during the view did load function in run time (using code). I am new to swift and i couldn't find anything like this on the internet. Here is the code that i am using:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import iAd
class gamePlay: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    var tempChoice : Int = 0
    var counter = 0

    @IBAction func b4(sender: UIButton) {
        tempChoice = 4
        counter = counter + 1
        checkAnswer()
    }

    func checkAnswer(){
    print(tempChoice)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }
```

in the viewDidLoad function i am trying to type

```
b4.setBackgroundImage.......etc.
```

but it is giving me an error saying that b4 does not have a set background image method or attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access UIButton you need to set it as outlet, not it's action. Notice that you can change background in b4 function because you have UIButton available.

Comment: But if it is an outlet, how do i tell the program to execute specific code when it is pressed?

Comment: You can have both. You can have action as IBAction and outlet as IBOutlet. One is reference to event/function, another to component.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot, if you could just tell what code to use on the outlet? that would be great!

Comment: Just open Assistant editor (top right corner, two circles), hold ctrl and drag object to file where you want to insert your outlet. Also give it a name to use in class.

Comment: yes i understand how to make the outlet, i am asking about the code to change the background image of the outlet.

Comment: button.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)